# Get value of variable on doInBackground() SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, local-variables

I must use SwingWorker to update EDT, so I write a method like this:

```
protected String var;
private void doSomething(){
    SwingWorker<Void, String> = new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){
        protected Void doInBackground(){
        var = "something";
        }
    };
}
```

How I get var value on the method above?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe post an error message or add code that uses the `doSomething` method given.

Comment: @FriendFX so I want go receive $var value outside the method. Something like this: System.out.println(var); and it'll be printed out "something", but not null.

Answer (score 1):

## You can...

Call `publish` and pass it the value, which will (eventually) be passed to `process`

## You can...

Return the value from the `doInBackground` method, which can be obtained by calling `get` after the worker has completed (you'd probably use a `PropertyChangeListener` to determine when the state changes)

## You could...

Devise you own interface to pass information out of the worker, but I'd still be using the `publish`/`process` functionality to get it back into the EDT.

Have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details